# Call to undefined method connect::prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

Every time I try to execute the query it shows:

> fatal error: Call to undefined method connect::prepare()

```
      class connect {

            private static $instance = null;
            private $pdo;

            private function __construct() {
                try{
                    $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=comment', 'root', '');
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }

            public static function getInstance() {
                if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
                    self::$instance = new connect();
                }
                return self::$instance;
            }
        }
```

// this in another page require_once 'connect.php';

```
class users {
    public $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = connect::getInstance();
    }      



    public function insertComment($user_id, $comment_text, $time) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('','$user_id', '$comment_text', '$time')";
        $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $this->query->execute();

    }

}

$user = new users;
$user_id = 10;
$comment_text = 'hello everyone';
$time = date("y/m/d - h:i:s");
$user->insertComment($user_id, $comment_text, $time);
```

Comment: In connect, you have PDO in a $pdo property.  In users, you have connect in a $pdo property.  To access PDO from users, you would then need to use `$this->pdo->pdo`.  This is where naming is going to get confusing for you.

Comment: it dosen't work can you explain more to get the whole idea

Comment: my tip is to get rid of your class 'connect'. PDO already is a fully equipped db-class. no need to wrap that in a custom one!

Comment: no another idea !! without removing the connect class !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In connect, you have PDO in a `$pdo` property. In users, you have connect in a `$pdo` property. To access PDO from users, you would then need to use `$this->pdo->pdo`. This is where naming is going to get confusing for you.

If you're only using this class to maintain one instance of PDO (singleton pattern), then there is no reason to use magic functions here, just return the PDO object in getInstance() instead of an instance of connect:

```
        /**
         * @return PDO
        */
        public static function getInstance() {
            if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new connect();
            }
            return self::$instance->pdo;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want `$this->pdo->pdo->prepare($sql);`, which is currently not accessible because `$pdo` is currently private in your class `connect`.

`$this->pdo` refers to your first (what appears to be database class `connect`), where you're then assigning `$this->pdo` again to be the actual PDO database class you're trying to reach (Add this to your `connect` class).

You could use the magic method [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to forward these requests to the parent PDO class:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if ( method_exists($this->pdo, $method) )
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this-pdo, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must understand encapsulation in Object Oriented Programming. When you declare a variable as private , it cannot be resolved outside of the class. Let me say you are declaring

```
private $pdo
```

You cannot see that variable in User class its only visiable in connect class. 
In your user class you have assing $pdo to connect instance (singleton instance) but when you use $pdo in user class you try to access native pdo which is not . 
So please use getter / setter for private variables. In your connect class :

```
function getPDO(){

    return $this->pdo;
    }
    // You dont need setter because you may will not use another driver in lifecyle
```

So when you want to call database driver you use this shortcut without doubt

```
connect::getInstance()->getPDO();
```

Please don't hesistate to ask anything in comments . Hope Helps!!!